# jQuery click gridview row in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying to figure out how to allow the user to click a row in a gridview in a master page. Ultimately I want the user to be redirected to another page with a values from the gridview (hiddenfield column) to be the querystring value of the page redirected to.

A this point I can only get to the gridview itself. I cannot get the row or the cell from  the gridview.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id$=LeagueGV]').click(function() { alert('gridview  clicked'); });
        //window.location = "/League_Admin.aspx?LID=" + $(this).find('LeagueHidden').value();
        //});
    });
</script>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="LeagueGV" DataKeyNames="LeagueID" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="LeagueHidden" Value='<%# Eval("LeagueID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LeagueIDLabel" Text='<%#Eval("LeagueID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LeagueName" HeaderText="League Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple problems with what you have. First off, your `GridView`'s ID won't be rendered as "LeagueGV", nor will the hidden field be "LeagueHidden". It will be mangled to be part of a chain of its parent `NamingContainer`'s IDs.

Secondly, jQuery syntax for using IDs can be as simple as `$('#yourId')`. The syntax you're using is old.

Thirdly, I wouldn't recommend adding a click event to a `table` or a `tr`. It's not an expected behavior by many users and could be confusing.

Unless you're hoping for unobtrusive Javascript, my first suggestion would be to have an `HyperLinkField` instead of a `TemplateField`, then you could override the `OnDataBound` event for the `GridView` and add an `onclick` attribute to the link when it renders that includes the LeagueID.

Comment: Thanks Cory. The Gridview is not rendered as "LeagueGV" but the above jQuery *does* find the gv. 

But more importantly it's interesting you say 'it's an unexpected event'. I never really thought of it and web ui is certainly not my strong point. 

I have a clickable gridivew in another project that I hack together with rowdatabound to make it 'clickable' and I was trying to expand on it. Clearly a hyperlink makes things a lot easier.

Comment: update - $('#LeagueGV') does not find the gridview in the content of the master page. The above syntax was the only way I could find the gv in the master page.

Comment: You're right -- your syntax means: find all elements whose IDs *end* with "LeagueGV", which would work better than what I suggested. Also, having a row being clickable isn't necessarily a bad thing, you just have to make it's supported by the browsers you're targeting. And you might want to give users hints that it's clickable, such as changing the cursor to be the hand and highlighting the row on hover.